# Is mediaStreamTrack in original w3c specification

Tags: html, w3c

I need to know whether "**mediaStreamTrack**" is defied in original **W3C** standards/spec.
Or it is just some other API(de-facto maybe) because i tried to find it among w3c standards on their site but couldn't find. Of course i did found it in some drafts but i guess draft doesn't represent the official standards.

If it is in the standards could someone please provide me some link.

Comment: It would be useful to link to the drafts you found.

Answer (score 0):

The "Media Capture and Streams" specification - https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/ - *is* intended to become a W3C Recommendation (it says so in the "Status of This Document" section).

It's just that the W3C [process](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/Process-20051014/tr.html#rec-advance) is quite comprehensive and thus relatively slow, and the status of the spec is "Last Call Working Draft" (as of April 2016) and it will need to go through several further stages before being called a W3C Recommendation.

By the way, I'm not sure why you care about this, since it seems an accepted fact that:

> The power is with browser makers. As Ian Hickson of WHATWG said, it doesn’t matter what the specs say if browsers don’t implement them.
>
> *(Bruce Lawson - [On HTML5 vs Living Standard, W3C vs WHATWG](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2014/on-html5-vs-living-standard-w3c-vs-whatwg/))*